# How to add Outlook signature to email from command line when a body is included?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to include a signature when generating an Outlook email from the command line?

Right now, I am using the following command syntax to start a new email:

```
OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.note 
    /m "?subject=SubjectLine&body=BodyOfEmail
    /a "filename.txt"
```

This is working just fine except that the new message does not include my standard signature.

If I omit the `body` parameter, the signature **is** appended. Is there any way to still have Outlook add the signature even though a `body` was specified?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue when adding the body parameter. Personally I'd like to suggest including the signature in the body content as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way, sorry. Outlook expects the full body (including possible signature) and thus, doesn't append the signature. Also, there is no command line switch to append the signature to the existing text: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Outlook

Comment: Thank you. I've decided to just copy the body to clipboard and paste when the new message opens up instead. Bummer.

Comment: You can also keep writing to the body then manually insert the Signature from the Ribbon 
(Insert Tab | Include Group | Signature pull down).